# can't access postgres file pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am getting this error when I run db:create:

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "wandrr"
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/home/jack/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/home/jack/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
....Edit out 40 more of these warnings...
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"wandrr_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"wandrr", "password"=>nil}
```

I figured out that I have to edit pg_hba.conf. The problem is that it won't open. It keeps telling me I don't have permission to use this file. So how do I get permission? I'm running ubuntu 12.10, rails 1.9.3, and postgres 9.1.

Comment: Did you try to edit it with sudo: `sudo vi pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: yeh... nothing shows up. I thought it is suposed to be filled with text?

Comment: Mine is empty too. It may be something else. Can you login from the command line?

Comment: I was able to edit when I opened it with gedit. Maybe it's just the text editor?

Comment: @JackJenkins If you didn't specify a path and your current directory wasn't the location of `pg_hba.conf`, then `sudo vi pg_hba.conf` would've tried to open `pg_hba.conf` in the current directory (probably your home folder), not found it, and started editing a new file that'd be created on save. You'd need to specify the full path, like `sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` for Pg installed from Ubuntu packages. To get the path use `SHOW hba_file;` in `psql`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First note down the location of `pg_hba.conf` on your system. If you don't know it but you can connect, connect to Pg with PgAdmin-III or `psql` and run:

```
SHOW hba_file;
```

to get the location of `pg_hba.conf`. It's location is pretty standard; on Ubuntu it'll be in `/etc/postgresql/[major.minor]/main/pg_hba.conf` eg `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf`. On most other distros it'll be under `/var/lib/pgsql/` or `/var/lib/postgresql`, either directly or in versioned directory.

To edit this file you must specify the full path or change directory to its location first. Say:

```
sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

If you prefer a friendlier text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

or replace "nano" with your preferred editor, like `gedit`.

Once you save your changes, remember to reload the PostgreSQL service to have them take effect. On Ubuntu you want:

```
pg_ctlcluster 9.1 main reload
```

Comment: when I do `sudo gedit pg_hba.conf` my directory adds a pg_hba.conf~ in addition to pg_hba.conf. What's the best way to edit the pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: oh man after 1:30 h searching for solution this helped me!  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following Crag's advice worked well.

For his last step, you have to sudo into the database superuser in order to get the PostgreSQL service to reload:

```
sudo -u postres pg_ctlcluster 9.1 main reload
```

These steps also work for Debian Sid systems.

Answer (score 1):

To edit `pg_hba.conf`, you can try editing as the `postgres` user:

- switch to the `postgres` user

  `sudo su postgres`
- run `psql`
- `SHOW hba_file;` as a query in psql to get the location
- `nano *the file location*`(*not* `sudo nano` as that will attempt the editing operation as the root user)